# How to specify pass analysis ("-Rpass", ...) in Clang for a specific file?

Tags: c++, clang

I want to pass to Clang something like `-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize` for a specific translation unit regardless of command line options.

Somewhere (I *think*, but can't find it now) I'd read that the way to do it was:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic "-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize"
// Code
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

for example. However, Clang complains that

> pragma diagnostic expected 'error', 'warning', 'ignored', 'fatal', 'push', or 'pop' [-Wunknown-pragmas]

Is there any way to achieve this without build system help?